# Difference between /etc/crontab and "crontab -e"

Tags: linux, unix, cron, crontab, cronjob

What is the difference between the crontab located in `/etc/crontab` and the crontab that can be edited using `crontab -e`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

As Ignacio said, `/etc/crontab` is the system wide crontab.

The format of `/etc/crontab` is like this:

```
# m h dom mon dow user      command
*   *  *   *   *  someuser  echo 'foo'
```

while `crontab -e` is per user, it's worth mentioning with no `-u` argument the crontab command goes to the current users crontab.  You can do `crontab -e -u <username>` to edit a specific users crontab.

Notice in a per user crontab there is no 'user' field.

```
# m h  dom mon dow  command
*   *   *   *   *   echo 'foo'
```

An aspect of crontabs that may be confusing is that root also has its own crontab.  e.g. `crontab -e -u root` will not edit `/etc/crontab`  See [Configuring cron](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/configtuning-cron.html).

In most Linux distros, per user crontabs are typically stored in: `/var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username>` (vixie-cron).

RHEL based distributions are stored in `/var/spool/cron/<username>`.  (cronie)

Comment: FYI, the path given above is incorrect: per-user crontabs are stored in /var/spool/cron/crontabs/<username> (I tried twice to submit this simple correction.)

Comment: ... and it's corrected now.

Comment: Actually, it's stored in `/var/spool/cron/root` for root's per-user crontab on a RHEL 6 system.  Haven't checked Ubuntu, but saying "typically" seems a bit of a stretch.

Comment: @Wildcard I think "typically" is a fair word to use.  RHEL distros ship w/ "cronie" (and anacron I believe) which is their fork of ISC-Cron/vixie cron.  I don't think that's a stretch, in any case I've updated my answer to include more detail.

Comment: For a quick lookup of the paths across distros, search for the string `path[crontabs]` in [the CFEngine "paths" library](https://github.com/cfengine/masterfiles/blob/master/lib/paths.cf) and check the context (the preceding context lines look like e.g. `redhat::`).  There's more variation than you think; e.g. SUSE puts them in `/var/spool/cron/tabs`.  (Abstracting distro differences is one of the reasons CFEngine was originally created, so it's often a good reference.)

Answer (score 6):

One is the system crontab and can only be edited by root, and the other is the user crontab and can be edited by a user and exists per user.